# LESSC to compile to a custom path using environment variable

Tags: intellij-idea, less, environment-variables, webstorm, file-watcher

Bottom line **I need lessc to compile my main.less file to $CATALINA_EC_TMP/main.css**

---

I'm working on this project, where I need to generate multiple output css files originating from the same source (LESS file) using LESSC.

So with Jet Brain's (WebStorm or IntelliJ Idea) File Watcher, I don't get much of options to save the output files to a custom path using an environment variable.

The reason why I use an environment variable is because some of the outputted files is in a temporary path (it changes whenever I deploy with ant)

---

That said ...

This is my Environment Variable:

```
$CATALINA_EC_TMP = '/foo/bar/'
```

and it's changing so in the next deployment, it won't be */foo/bar/* anymore.

and this is the command line that's being executed by my IDE to compile less files

```
/usr/local/bin/lessc --no-color main.less
```

I need lessc to compile my main.less file to *$CATALINA_EC_TMP/main.css*

so the resulting file would be in that case */foo/bar/main.css* or wherever the $CATALINA_EC_TMP value is.

I hope that there's a solution to this, anyway if it doesn't exist I think I'll use fswatcher to copy my generated css files into my destinations whenever I compile.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/lessc main.less $CATALINA_EC_TMP/main.css`?

Comment: I already tried that, this compiles the main.css to a new created directory called $CATALINA_EC_TMP in the current path where main.less is